# Keep variable inside another function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am lost in this concept. This is my code and what it does is just asking what is your name.

```
askName = do
  name <- getLine
  return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
       putStrLn "Greetings once again.  What is your name?"
       askName
```

However, How can I access in my `main` the variable name taken in askName?

This is my second attempt:

```
askUserName = do
  putStrLn "Hello, what's your name?"  
  name <- getLine  
  return name

sayHelloUser name = do
  putStrLn ("Hey " ++ name ++ ", you rock!")

main = do
  askUserName >>=  sayHelloUser
```

I can now re-use the `name` in a callback way, however if in main I want to call name again, how can I do that? (avoiding to put `name <- getLine`  in the main, obviously)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can imagine that you ask the name in order to print it, then let's rewrite it.
In pseudo code, we have

```
main =   
    print "what is your name"  
    bind varname with userReponse    
    print varname
```

Your question then concern the second instruction.
Take a look about the semantic of this one.

1. **userReponse** is a function which return the user input (getLine)
2. **varname** is a var
3. **bind** *var* **with** *fun* : is a function which associate a var(varname) to the output of a function(getLine)

Or as you know in haskell everything is a function then our semantic is not well suited.
We need to revisit it in order to respect this idiom. According to the later reflexion the semantic of our **bind** function become **bind** *fun* **with** *fun*

As we cannot have variable, to pass argument to a function, we need, at a first glance, to call another function, in order to produce them. Thus we need a way to chain two  functions, and it's exactly what's **bind** is supposed to do. Furthermore, as our example suggest, an evaluation order should be respected and this lead us to the following rewriting **with** *fun* **bind** *fun*

That's suggest that bind is more that a function it's an operator.
Then for all function f and g we have **with** f **bind** g.
In haskell we note this as follow

```
f >>= g
```

Furthermore, as we know that a function take 0, 1 or more argument and return 0, 1 or more argument.
We could refine our definition of our **bind** operator.
In fact when f doesn't return any result we note **>>=** as **>>**
Applying, theses reflexions to our pseudo code lead us to

```
main = print "what's your name" >> getLine >>= print
```

Wait a minute, How the bind operator differ from the dot operator use for the composition of two function ?

It's differ a lot, because we have omit an important information, bind doesn't chain two function but it's chain two **computations unit**. And that's the whole point to understand why we have define this operator.

Let's write down a **global computation** as a sequence of **computation unit**.

```
f0 >>= f1 >> f2 >> f3 ... >>= fn
```

As this stage a **global computation** could be define as a **set** of **computation** unit with two operator **>>=**, **>>**.

How do we represent **set** in computer science ?
Usually as **container**.

Then a global computation is a **container** which contain some **computation unit**. On this container we could define some operator allowing us to move from a **computation unit** to the next one, taking into account or not the result of the later, this is ours **>>=** and **>>** operator.

As it's a **container** we need a way to **inject** value into it, this is done by the **return** function. Which take an object and inject it into a **computation**, you could check it through is signature.

```
return :: a -> m a -- m symbolize the container, then the global computation
```

As it's a **computation** we need a way to manage a failure, this done by the **fail** function.
In fact the interface of a **computation** is define by a class

```
class Computation  
    return  -- inject an objet into a computation 
    >>=     -- chain two computation
    >>      -- chain two computation, omitting the result of the first one
    fail    -- manage a computation failure
```

Now we can refine our code as follow

```
main :: IO ()
main = return "What's your name" >>= print >> getLine >>= print
```

Here I have intentionally include the signature of the main function, to express the fact that we are in the global **IO computation** and the resulting output with be **()** (as an exercise enter **$ :t print** in ghci).
If we take more focus on the definition for **>>=**, we can emerge the following syntax

```
f >>= g <=> f >>= (\x -> g)  and f >> g <=> f >>= (\_ -> g)
```

And then write

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    return "what's your name" >>= \x ->
    print x                   >>= \_ -> 
    getLine                   >>= \x -> 
    print x
```

As you should suspect, we certainly have a special syntax to deal with **bind** operator in computational environment. You're right this is the purpose of **do syntax**
Then our previous code become, with do syntax

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- return "what's your name"
    _ <- print x  
    x <- getLine              
    print x
```

If you want to know more take a look on [monad](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/monads.html)

---

**As mentioned by leftaroundabout, my initial conclusion was a bit too enthusiastic**

You should be shocked, because we have break **referential transparency** law (x take two different value inside our sequence of instruction), but it doesn't matter anymore,because we are into a **computation**, and a **computation** as defined later is a **container** from which we can derive an interface and this interface is designed to manage, as explain, the **impure** world which correspond to the real world.

Comment: Actually, you haven't broken referential transparency by letting `x` take two different values. Those are simply _two different variables_, they just both happen to be called `x`. You can do that without monads, e.g. `let x=1 in let x="surprise!" in x` will evaluate to "surprise", and it's clear that the two `x` symbols aren't the same variable because they have different type. The `x=1` still exists and keeps the same value, it's only _shadowed_ by the other definition. – It **is** possible to actually modify values destructively in monads, but that requires e.g. `STRef`s.

Comment: @zurgl: Thank you for writing your answer. It's been *the* most helpful text I have read on this subject. Many texts about monads are long and difficult. That's not a bad thing, but thanks to your very concise answer, those texts become a lot easier to follow. Well done. +1

Answer (score 3):

Return the name from askname. In Haskell its not idiomatic to access "global" variables:

```
askName :: IO String
askName = do
  name <- getLine
  return name

main :: IO ()
main = do
       putStrLn "Greetings once again.  What is your name?"
       name <- askName
       putStrLn name
```

Now the only problem is tht the askName function is kind of pointless, since its now just an alias to `getLine`. We could "fix" that by putting the question inside askName:

```
askName :: IO String
askName = do
  putStrLn "Greetings once again.  What is your name?"
  name <- getLine
  return name

main :: IO ()
main = do
       name <- askName
       putStrLn name
```

---

Finally, just two little points: its usually a good idea to put type declarations when you are learning, to make things explicit and help compiler error messages. Another thing is to remember that the "return" function is only used for monadic code (it is *not* analogous to a traditional return statement!) and sometimes we could have ommited some intermediary variables:

```
askName :: IO String
askName = do
  putStrLn "Greetings once again.  What is your name?"
  getLine
```

Comment: omitting doesnt always work, does it? askName = do
  getLine
  putStrLn "Greetings once again.  What is your name?" doesnt work though

Comment: @haskellguy Right.  The return value of a `do` block is the return value of the last statement in the block.  That's why omitting works if you have `getLine` as the final statement in your block.  All the `return` at the end of a block does is (possibly) change the return value of the block.

Comment: Second question. Missingno way explains things but doesnt totally solve my problem. What if I create new variables (multiple variables) in askName and I want to reuse them?

Comment: @haskellguy: Return a single tuple of all the things.

Comment: @haskellguy: Another possibility is refactoring the askName function to receive the greeting string as a parameter. This way the main function calls askName multiple times, putting each result in whatever variable it wants. I would prefer to only return a tuple or struct in situations where it makes sense to define a data abstraction.

Comment: @haskellguy: Another thing: If you start getting too confused with the do notation and the monads, I would recommend working on problems that can be solved with pure code first (where all the IO you do is reading the input and writing the output). I remember I used to be really confused about IO and how to code with do notation until I finally "got" monads.