# Monadic impurity and Haskell's purity. How they are combined?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

How does the monad construct help to maintain purity (in Haskell) while at the same time doing impure things? When for example you give `print "Hello"` are you executing pure or impure code? It is a very subtle detail but something that helps better understand the idea of purity and impurity in functional languages.

Comment: [You can take a look at my answer on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201994/keep-variable-inside-another-function-in-haskell/14206044#14206044)  
May be it can help you.

Answer (score 20):

The expression

```
print "Hello"
```

is indeed pure. As it doesn't print anything, but rather constructs something that, when executed, prints "Hello".

Here is an analogy:

A monk writes on a sheet of paper:

```
Go to a bordell and do filthy things with the prostitutes there.
```

Can we accuse the monk because of adultery, just because he wrote an instruction to engage in adultery?

Answer (score 6):

The question in stackoverflow may answer your question: [In what sense is the IO Monad pure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063778/in-what-sense-is-the-io-monad-pure)

In short, monad itself is **pure**, but it can issue **impure** instructions.
To be a little bit more specific, monads can be viewed as a series of composable computation descriptions. Some of these computations may be dirty(i.e. have side-effect), but description itself is totally pure and clean.